# Generic bluetooth joystick driver/udev rules

Tags: drivers, xorg, bluetooth, udev, joystick

This is my first question since I'm less than a week old Ubuntu user. I officially switched from W10 on Friday. I have managed to find answers to all my n00b questions until today when I tried to install Steam and the controllers I'm using with my favorite relaxing Euro Truck Simulator 2.

Anyways..

I am trying to pair a cheap bluetooth joystick [Magicsee R1](https://www.geekmaxi.com/img/p/2/0/5/8/2058-thickbox_default.jpg). I have installed all the joystick packages that might support it but until now it doesn't show as a joystick in ETS2. It does however show up when I test it with jstest-gtk. I have also installed xorg-joystick-packages. From my n00b research i figured that it might be the udev that gives the wrong instruction to the system about what the device is. I got this thing by digging in the Xorg.0.log. Hope it helps somehow.

[    76.726] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Magicsee R1 (/dev/input/mouse2)

[    76.726] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.

[    76.726] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.

[    76.734] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Magicsee R1      (/dev/input/js0)

[    76.734] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.

[    76.734] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.

[    76.788] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Magicsee R1      (/dev/input/event9)

[    76.788] (**) Magicsee R1     : Applying InputClass "libinput pointer catchall"

[    76.788] (**) Magicsee R1     : Applying InputClass "libinput keyboard catchall"

[    76.788] (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'Magicsee R1     '

[    76.791] (II) systemd-logind: got fd for /dev/input/event9 13:73 fd 25 paused 1

[    76.791] (II) systemd-logind: releasing fd for 13:73

P.S. Also, an advice of how to paste this above next time would be very helpful.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To get emulatorstation and Kodi to recognise the Magicsee R1 (on retropie 4.14.30-v7+) I had to put the following in `/etc/udev/rules.d/99-gamepad.rules`:

```
SUBSYSTEM=="input", ATTRS{name}=="Magicsee R1       ", MODE="0666", ENV{ID_INPUT_JOYSTICK}="1"
```

I assume this should allow ETS2 to see the Magicsee R1 as well. I think the space in the ATTRS{name} isn't necessary but that's how it is given by udevadm. I find mode C (M+C) works better than B because B generates multiple button events for two of the buttons whereas C only generates one event for all of the buttons.

Hope this helps.